# Cypress setCookie not working as expected

Tags: cookies, cypress

I have added a command `getCSRFToken` that is used by other commands to get the CSRF token for making requests to my app:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("getCSRFToken", () => {
  cy.getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN').then((cookie) => {
    if (!cookie) {
      return cy.request('HEAD', '/')
        .its('headers')
        .then((headers) => {
          const token = headers['x-xsrf-token'];
          if (!token) {
            throw new Error('XSRF token not found');
          }

          return cy.setCookie('XSRF-TOKEN', token)
            .then(() => token);
        });
    }

    return cookie.value;
  });
});
```

The portion that makes a `HEAD` request is for usage of this function when no pages have yet been visited in the test, for example when making `POST` requests to create test data.

AFAICT this looks like it should work to me, however it seems subsequent calls to `getCookie` doesn't actually retrieve anything:

[image]

[image]

I thought returning the `setCookie` promise and `getCookie` promise might make a difference but it does not seem like that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Cypress clears up all cookies before every test is run. They have an api to keep a cookie for the next test execution which is [Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce](http://Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('XSRF-TOKEN'))

Back to your use case, you can call **Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('XSRF-TOKEN')** in the suite-level beforeEach in every suite where you want to get the token. If you don't want to repeat the call, you can move it inside your **getCSRFToken** command.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getCSRFToken", () => {
  Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('XSRF-TOKEN')
  cy.getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN').then((cookie) => {
    .....
  });
});
```